# How to add page under a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, urls, page-template

I would like to add a page that uses a custom template (page-coffee-about.php), so it will appear under a custom post type called "coffee". The URL of the custom page should be domain.com/coffee/about/. I already have a URL for domain.com/coffee that uses archive-coffee.php.

I've searched and tried several different things (creating a coffee parent page, adding hierarchical => true to the register_post_type() for coffee, along with supports "page-attributes"), but I keep getting a page not found error.

Please note that I am running WordPress 3.7 and cannot upgrade!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any answer given will assume the current latest version ( 4.1 at time of writing ), why is it that upgrading from 3.7 not possible?

Comment: It's over my head -- not in my control. :)

Comment: You should insist on it, for security reasons if not others. If your employers and management will allow you to make code changes but won't update WordPress, then their priorities are confused. If you're on a managed host and they haven't updated past 3.7 then you should seriously consider moving host

Comment: Page not found means it is not a template problem, rather permalink issue. Try setting your permalink to default and than visit the page!

Comment: @FiazHusyn you just made my day. No joke! You don't even want to know how much time I wasted on that. Please add that as the answer, and I will happily select it as the answer, just in case anyone else has this issue in the future.

Comment: Glad to have helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Page not found" means it is not a template problem, rather permalink issue. Try setting your permalink to default and than visit the page!